# Installing latest version of gmsh

Tags: installation, upgrade

How can I install latest version of gmsh, which is gmsh 3.0.7 on ubuntu 16.04LTS please?
Using `sudo apt install gmsh` it only installs gmsh 2.10.1.

I also did update and upgrade my system but still only version 2.10.1.

Any suggestion please?
Cheers

Comment: 3.0.6 https://launchpad.net/~nschloe/+archive/ubuntu/gmsh-nightly ... Ubuntu 18.04 : 3.0.7 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I prefix this by saying I'm nothing like an expert, but this worked for me:

Uninstall the repository version:

`sudo apt-get remove gmsh`

Download a zipped copy of the latest stable release for linux from the gmsh website:

http://gmsh.info/#Download

Unzip gmsh:

`tar -xvzf gmsh-3.0.6-Linux64.tgz` (or whatever version you've downloaded)

This makes a folder gmsh-3.0.6-Linux64 containing gmsh which is portable. Put it somewhere you can find it. I put it in my home directory.
Navigate to the bin folder:

`cd ~/gmsh-3.0.6-Linux64/bin`

From the bin folder you can start gmsh by typing:

`./gmsh`

I made it generally available at the command line by editing my .bashrc, adding this line:

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/bob/gmsh-3.0.6-Linux64/bin"`

You will need to make the path appropriate for your location.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

if it can help someone here, I recently compiled GMSH from source without difficulty, simply with the typical combination of *cmake* and *make*; their GitLab repository explains these few steps to follow
https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh
Although this may vary, pay attention to few libraries which weren't present on my fresh Ubuntu installation (libpng, libjpeg, and FLTK libraries), cmake properly highlighted these missing libraries. FLTK is needed for the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has gmsh version 4.4.1 in the official repositories. So installation is again simply this:

```
sudo apt install gmsh
```